# Running Multiple website on windows XP 64

Tags: windows-xp, iis-6, 64-bit

I'm running windows xp 64, which is really xp over server 2003, It runs iis6, which is capable of running multiple websites, but the XP version doesn't let me, I would assume this could be changed with a registry edit? any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

That's a limitation of the Windows XP version of IIS. It's not something you can just change with a registry change (and the license says you can't do that either).

Even thought WXP x64 is really just W2K3 x64, the limitation is still in the product.

Comment: I don't condone people breaking licensing, but there are ways around this restriction, not the way you mention, but there are ways.  I did a quick search, and found several methods for getting past this restriction.

Comment: There definitely are. Being "Microsoft Certified" as I am (though I don't particularly like to admit it in public), I am contractually bound not to be party toward violating the terms of Microsoft's licenses. I've just gotten so conditioned that I don't even mention it anymore.  >sigh<

Comment: I am with you there Evan... Microsoft Certified myself... so I can't be party to it either, I can just state my objections